# Bash split string

Tags: string, bash, awk, split, cut

I have the following data in array:

```
MY_ARR[0]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name1,name2'" 
MY_ARR[1]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name3,name4,name5'"
MY_ARR[2]=".name.exe 'word1 word2'"
MY_ARR[3]="name.exe"
MY_ARR[4]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name1'"
MY_ARR[5]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name.exe, name4.exe, name5.exe'"
```

I want to divide it into two variables: `$file` and `$parameter`.

Example:

```
file="./path/path2/name.exe"
parameter="'word1 word2' 'name1,name2'"
```

I can do it with awk:

```
parameter=$(echo "${MY_ARR[1]}" | awk -F\' '{print $2 $4}')
file=$(echo "${MY_ARR[1]}" | awk -F\' '{print $1}')
```

This needs to remove trailing spaces and looks to complicated.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like the separator between the fields is an space. Hence, you can use `cut` to split them:

```
file=$(echo "${MY_ARR[1]}" | cut -d' ' -f1)
parameter=$(echo "${MY_ARR[1]}" | cut -d' ' -f2-)
```

- `-f1` means the first parameter.
- `-f2-` means everything from the second parameter.

Comment: yes, I know about cut. I used it with my first try. I refused to use it because I was afraid to miss the third and fouth fieleds if the are spaces... Need to check!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `read`:

```
$ read file parameter <<< ${MY_ARR[1]}
$ echo "$file"
./path/path2/name.exe
$ echo "$parameter"
'word1 word2' 'name3,name4,name5'
```

Comment: This is the better solution, as it doesn't require multiple new processes to accomplish the task (one for the command substitution, two for either side of the pipeline).

Answer (score 2):

Given this array:

```
    MY_ARR[0]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name1,name2'"
    MY_ARR[1]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name3,name4,name5'"
    MY_ARR[2]=".name.exe             'word1 word2'"
    MY_ARR[3]="name.exe"
    MY_ARR[4]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name1'"
    MY_ARR[5]="./path/path2/name.exe 'word1 word2' 'name.exe, name4.exe, name5.exe'"
```

Lets make 2 new arrays   MY_FILES  and  MY_PARAMETERS

```
    for  MY_ARR_INDEX in  ${!MY_ARR[*]}  ;  do

         ######
         # Set the current file in new array.

              MY_FILES[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]=${MY_ARR[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]// *}

         ######
         # Set the current parameters in new array

         MY_PARAMETERS[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]=${MY_ARR[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]#* }

         ######
         # Show the user whats happening
         # (from here until done is just printing info.)

         printf "MY_FILES[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]=\"%s\"  ;  MY_PARAMETERS[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]=\"%s\"\n" \
         \
          "${MY_ARR[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]// *}"  "${MY_ARR[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]#* }"

    done


    MY_FILES[ 0 ]="./path/path2/name.exe"  ;  MY_PARAMETERS[ 0 ]="'word1 word2' 'name1,name2'"
    MY_FILES[ 1 ]="./path/path2/name.exe"  ;  MY_PARAMETERS[ 1 ]="'word1 word2' 'name3,name4,name5'"
    MY_FILES[ 2 ]=".name.exe"  ;  MY_PARAMETERS[ 2 ]="            'word1 word2'"
    MY_FILES[ 3 ]="name.exe"  ;  MY_PARAMETERS[ 3 ]="name.exe"
    MY_FILES[ 4 ]="./path/path2/name.exe"  ;  MY_PARAMETERS[ 4 ]="'word1 word2' 'name1'"
    MY_FILES[ 5 ]="./path/path2/name.exe"  ;  MY_PARAMETERS[ 5 ]="'word1 word2' 'name.exe, name4.exe, name5.exe'"
```

How to access each file:

```
    for  MY_ARR_INDEX in  ${!MY_FILES[*]}  ;  do

         CUR_FILE=${MY_FILES[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ] }

         echo "# Do something with this file: ${CUR_FILE}"

    done
```

Output:

```
    Do something with this file: ./path/path2/name.exe
    Do something with this file: ./path/path2/name.exe
    Do something with this file: .name.exe
    Do something with this file: name.exe
    Do something with this file: ./path/path2/name.exe
    Do something with this file: ./path/path2/name.exe
```

How to access each parameter :

```
    for  MY_ARR_INDEX in  ${!MY_PARAMETERS[*]}  ;  do

         CUR_FILE=${MY_FILES[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]}

         echo "# Do something with this parameter: ${CUR_FILE}"

    done
```

Output:

```
    Do something with this parameter: ./path/path2/name.exe
    Do something with this parameter: ./path/path2/name.exe
    Do something with this parameter: .name.exe
    Do something with this parameter: name.exe
    Do something with this parameter: ./path/path2/name.exe
    Do something with this parameter: ./path/path2/name.exe
```

Since ${!MY_FILES[ [*]} results in the index NUMBERS of array MY_FILES you can also use the same index numbers to access the other arrays.In this way, you may access multiple columns of data in the same loop. Like so:

```
    ################
    #
    # Print each file and matching parameter(s)
    #
    ################

    # Set a printf format string so we can print all things nicely.

    MY_PRINTF_FORMAT="#  %25s  %s\n"

    ################
    #
    # Print the column headings and use index numbers
    #
    #        to print adjacent array elements.
    #
    ################
    (

            printf   "${MY_PRINTF_FORMAT}"  "FILE" "PARAMETERS"    "----" "----------"

        for  MY_ARR_INDEX in  ${!MY_FILES[*]}  ;  do

             printf  "${MY_PRINTF_FORMAT}"  "${MY_FILES[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]}"  "${MY_PARAMETERS[ ${MY_ARR_INDEX} ]}"

        done
    )
```

Output :

```
                           FILE  PARAMETERS
                           ----  ----------
          ./path/path2/name.exe  'word1 word2' 'name1,name2'
          ./path/path2/name.exe  'word1 word2' 'name3,name4,name5'
                      .name.exe              'word1 word2'
                       name.exe  name.exe
          ./path/path2/name.exe  'word1 word2' 'name1'
          ./path/path2/name.exe  'word1 word2' 'name.exe, name4.exe, name5.exe'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, simplest and most portable way would be to just use two variations of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) expansion for this.

```
file="${MY_ARR[0]%%' '*}"
parameter="${MY_ARR[0]#*' '}"
```

**Explanation**

- `"${MY_ARR[0]%%' '*}"` - This removes the first space and anything after it, and returns remaining part
- `"${MY_ARR[0]#*' '}"` - This removes everything up to the first space, and returns the remaining part

For a more detailed explanation, see the `Parameter Expansion` section of the bash man page